# object not found, function display()

Tags: php, html

I get object not found on this after following another stack overflow question. any suggestions? I am trying to make it so when you press submit the php code is repeated (eventually it'll add the information too).

html code:

```
<form method="post" action="display()">
    <div class="form-group">    
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Text" name="caseName"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

the PHP code:

```
function    display()
{
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","xxx","xxx");
//    Check    connection
if    (mysqli_connect_errno())    {
echo    "Failed    to    connect    to    MySQL:    "    .    mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result    =    mysqli_query($con,"SELECT    *    FROM    caseStudies");
$row    =    mysqli_fetch_array($result);
for($i    =    0;    $i    <    1;    $i++)    {
echo    "<div    class='case'    id='case$i'>";
echo    "<div    class='row'>";
echo    "<div    class='header'>";
echo    '<h4>'    .    $row['caseName']    .    '</h4>';
echo    "</div>";
echo    "</div>";
echo    "<div    class='row'>";
echo    "<div    class='caseimg'>";
echo    '<img    src="'    .    $row['caseImage']    .    '"    class="Responsive    image"/>';
echo    "</div>";
echo    "<div    class='caseimg'>";
echo    '<img    src="'    .    $row['caseImage']    .    '"    class="Responsive    image"/>';
echo    "</div>";
echo    "<div    class='caseimg'>";
echo    '<img    src="'    .    $row['caseImage']    .    '"    class="Responsive    image"/>';
echo    "</div>";
echo    "</div>";
                            $i++;
}
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
display();
}    
?>
```

Comment: Simple: `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` is looking for a form element and is dependant on a named element called `submit` - it doesn't exist. Take this as an (*partial*) "answer".

Comment: Answers are soon to be rolling in like oranges... (*below*) whoever wants it... go for it.

Comment: You'll also want to change this `action="display()"` to `action=""`

Comment: there is a submit element?

Comment: Well well, will you lookah dat; my mistake. Sorry.

Comment: that's ok, thanks for answering. sorry if my question seems very simple. I am very new to PHP

Comment: Can you really submit directly to a function like this in PHP?

Comment: No you cant and you shouldn't. Be damned the day a user can invoke any function he wants in my server.

Comment: I guess there will be no oranges today; my predictions have been a bit off lately. Must be the "new SO".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `action` in `<form>` should be the URL to where the form data will be submitted to. It is not the name of a function.

Also, you are testing `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`. This condition will never be true. You don't have an input named `submit` in your form.

Comment: I am not sure I am following. the PHP is within the same document as the form so how would i submit it otherwise? Or am I being very silly

Comment: Just remove the text in `action=""`, and then use `if(isset($_POST['caseName'])){}`

Comment: You are telling it to post the data to the file named `display()`. I suppose such file doesn't exist. Just ommit this attribute to make the form post the data to the same file.

Comment: As per your edit: *"Also, you are testing if(isset($_POST['submit'])). This condition will never be true. You don't have an input named submit in your form."* -- Which.... is... what... [`I've been telling the OP from the beginning`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023483/object-not-found-function-display#comment37030695_24023483). But hey, what do I know, right? ;-)

Comment: sorry, yes I understand now. thank you to you both.

Comment: @user248305 Now, would I lie to you? ;-) and you're welcome.